# Find a vector in a Hilbert space, such that the inner product with a unit vector is $n^{-2/3}$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

I am trying to prepare for my exam in analysis, and I am stuck on this old exam question.

"Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space with an orthonormal basis (= maximal orthonormal system) $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$. Show that there exists $g,h \in \mathcal{H}$, such that $\langle g,e_n\rangle = \frac{1}{n^{4/3}}$, and $\langle h,e_n\rangle = \frac{1}{n^{2/3}}$. Find $\langle g,h\rangle$."

The hints I've been given is that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^\alpha}<\infty$ for $\alpha>1$, and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

I am a little confused by how to do this because it seems to me that the inner product isn't explicitly defined? How can I calculate it, if I don't know anything about what the inner product looks like? A friend of mine said I should use Parseval's identity, but I can't see how it helps me with this problem.

I have found in my textbook that $\langle g,h\rangle = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle g,e_n\rangle \overline{\langle h,e_n\rangle}$ for all $g,h\in\mathcal{H}$, and I'm thinking I can somehow use this property.

Comment: You can write $g$ and $h$ in terms of $e_n$ right? So basically $g=\sum_n g_n e_n$ where $g_n$ are the coefficients. To have the inner product of $g$ and $e_n$ equal to something means what? Try using the series to answer that question.

Comment: @Sashi I'm still not sure how to work out this problem. I simply don't understand how to use the information provided. The inner product is a generalization of the dot product, and I know it gives me a scalar. Other than that, I'm a little lost.

Comment: @ThomasShelby I have checked and double checked, and yes, it is $n^{-2/3}$. What I have a hard time understanding is how to explicitly show that the inner product $\langle g,e_n\rangle = n^{-4/3}$.

Comment: If you take $h=\sum_{n}\frac1 {n^{2/3}}e_n$, you will have $\langle h,e_n\rangle =\frac1 {n^{2/3}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $\mathcal H$ be a Hilbert space and $\{e_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ be an orthonormal set.
If $(c_n)_{n\geq1}$ is a sequence in $\mathbb C$ such that $\sum_{n\geq 1}|c_n|^2\lt \infty$, then $\sum_{n= 1}^{\infty}c_ne_n$ exists.

To see this, define $$y_k:= \sum_{i=1}^kc_ie_i$$ for all $k\in \mathbb N$. Then $(y_k)_{k\geq 1}$ is a sequence in $\mathcal H$. We have $$\|y_l-y_k\|^2=\left\|\sum_{i=k+1}^lc_ie_i\right\|^2 \leq \sum_{i=k+1}^l\|c_ie_i\|^2=\sum_{i=k+1}^l|c_i|^2$$ for some $l,k\in\mathbb N$ with $l\gt k$. Since $\sum_{n\geq 1}|c_n|^2\lt \infty$, the sum $\sum_{i=k+1}^l|c_i|^2$ can be made arbitrarily small for sufficiently large $l,k\in\mathbb N$. So $(y_k)_{k\geq1}$ is Cauchy in $\mathcal H$ and hence converges.

---

Now for a start, consider the sequence $\left(\frac1{n^{4/3}}\right)_{n\ge 1}.$  What do you know about $$\sum_{n= 1}^{\infty}{\left(\frac1{n^{4/3}}\right)}^2 ?$$

Comment: I feel stupid, but I can't see how this helps me. I don't see what $|| y_l - y_k||^2$ gives me.